# parsing external xml feed with jquery only works in safari

Tags: jquery, xml, safari, jsonp

so i have the below code, which parses an xml feed on a different server (ie www.site1.com) from a locally hosted file (on my computer). it works perfectly in safari. but doesnt work in chrome or firefox.

when i store the xml feed on the same server as the html file (ie both files on www.site2.com), the file parses fine in all browsers. the problem is, i need to be parsing the xml from an external server. how do i make this work? is it possible?

i feel like ive tried everything. callback functions, jsonp.js files, and all sorts of jquery options. but no dice. if anyone has any suggestions, i'd be real appreciative! thank you!

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://www.otherwebsite.com/external_feed.atom",
  dataType: "xml",
  success: parseXml
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your console. You are doing a cross domain ajax request. The only way you are able to achieve cross domain parsing, is with jsonp. Where are you grabbing the xml feed from? Maybe I can help you and try see if they have a jsonp example. This is an example of a jsonp url http://www.kiabuzz.co.za/?feed=json&callback=?. Paste it in replace of the above and you will see that the problem will disappear. Obviously the datatype will be json as opposed to xml.

As you can see that if the file is on the server the problem will disappear. Can you provide me with the url you are trying to grab the xml feed from?

Comment: thank you for the really quick reply! appreciate it.  
yup, youre right. that kiabuzz link parses fine. so it must be the feed i'm trying to use.  
[here is the one i am trying to parse](http://www.livingsocial.com/cities/905.atom)

Comment: I found the url "http://www.livingsocial.com/services/city/v2/cities?&callback=?". Problem is that the returned data is wrapped in an array so instead of hitting the success callback, the error callback gets hit. The error is a "parseError" because of the array returned. I am looking up a way to get around this.

Comment: thank you so much! if i had 15 reputation, i would up vote you to infinity.

Comment: You could mark the answer as correct if it did help you :) Have not had the time to find a way around the json wrapped in an array. Please post if you have come across the solution as I am very curious.

Comment: its weird because it parses fine in safari. i'll keep trying and will definitely post my results here i find anything! thanks again for your help :)

Comment: sorry. i dont really know what i'm doing, but... if anyone is ever having trouble with jquery/jsonp, ive managed to parse with php using this code.

`<?php 
    $myfeed = simplexml_load_file('http://www.livingsocial.com/cities/905.atom');
    foreach ($myfeed->entry as $dealinfo):
        $title=$dealinfo->title;
        $link=$dealinfo->link['href'];
  $price=$dealinfo->price;
  $value=$dealinfo->value;
  $savings=$dealinfo->savings;  
  echo $title . " " . $link . " " . $price . " " . $value . " " . $savings . "<br><br>"; 
    endforeach;
?>`